# Doubt in construction of Hintikka set (Chiswell and Hodges book)

Tags: logic

I have a doubt in the proof of Lemma 3.10.6 from the book Mathematical Logic by Chiswell and Hodges [page 92](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA92&dq=%22This%20is%20quite%20a%20busy%20proof%22&hl=en&source=newbks_fb&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22This%20is%20quite%20a%20busy%20proof%22&f=false). I don't understand the relationship between the list of formulas $\phi_0,\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3,\cdots$ and
the list of formulas $\psi_0,\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3,...$ . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Luckily I could find the book. What's happening is that you order the propostions by their Gödel numbering $\psi_0,\psi_1,\psi_2,\cdots$. Another order is made which the book illustrates as steps but written linearly you have $\psi_0,\;\psi_0,\psi_1,\;\psi_0,\psi_1,\psi_2,\;\psi_0,\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3$. So the relation is:
$\phi_0=\psi_0$
$\phi_1=\psi_0$
$\phi_2=\psi_1$
$\phi_3=\psi_0$
$\phi_4=\psi_1$
$\phi_5=\psi_2$
$\phi_6=\psi_0$
and so on.
The reason for this is as you are building the Hintikka extension let's say you left the previous ordering and are at step $i+1$ with $\Gamma_i$ and the sentence is $\psi_i\equiv\chi_1 \wedge\chi_2$ which is in $\Gamma_i$ Then $\Gamma_{i+1}=\Gamma_{i}\cup\{\chi_1,\chi_2\}$. But if let's say $\chi_1$ is a conjunction of two propositions that have Gödel numbering less than $i$ then at no step will they be added to $\Gamma$ and the extension would not be of Hintikka.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks for the answer.